# C++ Memory Address

Tags: c++, memory

Please excuse me if this is a repeated question

This is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "iostream"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char * name = "Hello";

    cout << "2" << endl;
    cout << "Address2 is " << &name <<  "   value at address is " << * (&name) << endl;
    cout << "Next address2 is " << &name + 1 << "   value at address is " << name + 1 << "  " << sizeof(char) << endl;

    cout << "3" << endl;
    cout << "Address3 is " << &name << "   value at address is " << name << endl;

    cout << "Next address3 is " << &name + sizeof name << "   value at address is " << name + sizeof name << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

and this is the output

1. Address2 is 003EFAA4 value at address is Hello   **// easy for me to understand**
2. Next Address2 is **003EFAA8 (This is where i struggle to understand. My understanding is the next address should be 003EFAA5 considering char is of 1 Byte?**
3. output same as 1
4. Next Address2 is **003EFAB4 (This is where i struggle to understand too. My understanding is the next address should be 003EFAA8 when address of variable name is 003EFAA4 considering size of char pointer is of 4 Byte?**

My understanding about memory is the addresses are referenced in terms of bytes. If that is true then why in number 3 above it gives me the address which is 4 bytes further and in number 4 above it gives me the next address that is 10 bytes further?

Any explanation would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `&name + 1` is different from `&(name + 1)`

Comment: Not yet sure what's the cause, but there is a mistake. It should be `const char * name = "Hello";`, as string literals are constant. It's strange that this compiled as the standard forbids this.

Comment: &(name + 1) does not compile. It gives me error something like  Error 1 error C2102: '&' requires l-value

Comment: @ScottHunter You can't apply `&` to a temporary.

Comment: By the way, one other pitfall here: you’re allowed to take an address one-past-the-end of an array such as `name`. The intended use is as a sentinel value: `while ( p < name + name_len )`. So, `(void*)(name + sizeof(name))` would have been legal, but `&name + sizeof(name)` is undefined behavior, and while you can calculate the address `name + sizeof(name)`, looking up its contents by passing it as a `char*` to `cout` is undefined behavior. For example, that address might not be mapped into the process’ address space and therefore cause a CPU fault if you try to access it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Next Address2 is 003EFAA8 (This is where i struggle to understand. My understanding is the next address should be 003EFAA5 considering char is of 1 Byte?

When you do `&name + 1` you go to the next address  of the type of `name`.  `name` is not a `char` though.  It is a `char*` and on your system a `char*` has a size of 4.  This is why it goes 4 bytes forward, as that is where the next `char*` could be located.

> Next Address2 is 003EFAB4 (This is where i struggle to understand too. My understanding is the next address should be 003EFAA8 when address of variable name is 003EFAA4 considering size of char pointer is of 4 Byte?

This is basically the same thing that is happening above, but instead of going to the next `char*`, you are going to the `sizeof name` next element which in this case is the fourth element.

Comment: Thank you very much for the so simple  explanation. I straightaway got it about the first bit in your answer. However could you please explain the second bit? I totally understood it when you said sizeof name (char * = 4) would add 16 bytes (4+4+4+4). But why the address is only 10 Bytes further? i.e 003EFAB4 - 003EFAA4 gives me 10 as answer so don't you think the next address should be 003EFABA? Whic would then give me 16 bytes?

Comment: @FaisalKhan `003EFAB4 - 003EFAA4` is `10` but you have to remember that it is `10` in hex.  `10` in hex is `16` in decimal.

Comment: again thank you for your explanation. When you say 10 in hex would be 16 in decimal that is a fair point i totally agree. However my understanding my memory is that it deals in Hex and not decimal or am i missing something here?

Comment: @FaisalKhan You are correct that the address are shown in hex.  `003EFAB4` is not only 10 bytes past `003EFAA4`.  the `10` is in hex and if you convert that to decimal it is 16 bytes. If we convert the address to decimal (to make the numbers all in the same base) then you have `4127412 - 4127396` which is 16.  Does that make sense?

Comment: i am sorry i am still confused. Lets say i have a pointer p1 pointing to a 2 bytes variable say name1 and is stored location 000A so if i do the p+1 it would give me the address 000C isn't it? so 000C - 000A would give me 2 in  Hex which is 2 in Decimal as well.

So does it mean when we talk about 4 * 4 bytes it would be  represented in hex as you mentioned BUT it would be 16 in decimal and not hex?

Comment: @FaisalKhan Sure.  But lets say you have pointer `p1` that is pointing to a 16 byte object.  If you do `p1 + 1` then `000A` becomes `001A` (10 becomes 26).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195640/discussion-between-faisal-khan-and-nathanoliver).

Comment: i am kind of getting there thank you. Could you please read my previous comment again and edit your last answer accordingly? Also could you please point me to any good resource to get my head around this fully? Thank you so much for your time

Comment: in your last answer, did you mean to say **10 becomes 16** ? as you have mentioned 10 becomes 26 that confused me? 4*4 is also 16 bytes and 16 bytes object would be same as 4*4 char * pointer?

Comment: @FaisalKhan I'll just continue the comment here.  So, if you have 4, 4 byte objects then you you have 4 * 4 which is 16.  So you have 16 bytes of space.  When you look at the address, well use `003EFAA4`, that address is in hex.  If you want to add 16 bytes to that address you don't add the 16 to get `003EFABA`. You need to convert 16 base10 (decimal) to what 16 would be in base16 (hexidecimal) since you need the same base to add the numbers together.  16 base10 is 10 base16.  If we add the `10` base16 to `003EFAA4` then we get `003EFAB4`.  Make sense?

Answer (score 7):

`&name` is of type `char**`. The way pointer arithmetic works, if you add to it, it increases that much times the size of `char*` (because a `char**` points to a `char*`, and this way it would point to the next `char*` if there were an array of `char*`). It looks like the size of `char*` is `4` on your system. So if `&name` is `003EFAA4`,  then `&name + 1`is `003EFAA8` (that's `4` more).

`sizeof name` is `4`, so if you add that to `&name` it increases by `16`. Hence whey you get `003EFAB4`, that's `0x10` (or `16`) more than `003EFAA4`.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to pointer arithmetics.

```
char *name = "hello";
```

`name` is a pointer to character. It stores the address of `"hello"` string literal, ie. the address of character `h` (the address of an array is equal (to the value) to the address of the first element of an array). You should note that string literals are immutable, you can't modify them. So it's best to change the type to `const char*`.

```
&name
```

This is a pointer to the variable name. Not a pointer to `"hello"` string literal, but a pointer to a pointer. The `003EFAA4` is the address of `name` variable. The variable was allocated by the compiler on stack inside the  `main()` function.

```
*(&name)
```

The `*&` rule (here) themselves out. So `*&name` is equal to `name`. This prints the value of the `name` pointer, ie. this is the pointer to `"hello"` string literal, ie. this is the pointer to the character `h` inside `"hello"` string literal. Not `&name`. Address of `h` character.

```
&name + 1
```

The `&name` has the `char **` type, ie. it as a pointer to a pointer to a character. From pointer arithmetics, the `&name + 1` is equal to the value to `(uintptr_t)&name + 1 * sizeof(*&name)`. `sizeof(*&name)` is `sizeof(name)` it is `sizeof(char*)`, so it's `(uintptr_t)&name + sizeof(char*)`. On your architecture `sizeof(char*)` is 4 bytes (32 bit system?), so the pointer is incremented by 4. Ie. `003EFAA4 + 4 = 003EFAA8`.

```
name + 1
```

The `name` has the type of `char*`. From pointer arithmetics `name + 1` is equal to `(uintptr_t)name + sizeof(*name)`. `sizeof(*name)` is `sizeof(char)`. `sizeof(char)` is defined to be equal 1. This prints the address of `e` char inside `"hello"` string literal.

```
&name + sizeof name
```

`&name` has the type of `char**`, so the value of `&name` is incremented `sizeof(name) * sizeof(char*) times. As`sizeof(name)`is equal to`sizeof(char*)`, this is`sizeof(char*) * sizeof(char*)`ie.`4*4 = 16` on your computer.

```
name + sizeof name
```

This increments the pointer `name` value by value of `sizoef(name) * sizeof(char)`. `sizeof(name)` is `sizeof(char*)` is `4` on your architecture, `sizeof(char)` is 1. So `name + sizeof name` is the address of character `o` inside `"hello"` string literal, ie. `003EFAA8`.

@edit rewritten some parts

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. From the last para in your answer, could we say that 'H' is stored at 003EFAA8 and 'e' is stored at 003EFAAC and so on... because char * is of 4 bytes? and if i had declared it as array it would have been like 'H' on 003EFAA8  and 'e' on 003EFAA9?

Comment: I wish i could have the option to select multiple accepted answer. Thank you for your time is the least i can say

Answer (score 5):

You've got one too many levels of indirection here.

`&name` is a char**, i.e. a pointer to a character pointer. This means that if you +1 then you add the size of a pointer, not the size of a character. `name` is already a char*.

The problem then is doing pointer arithmetic on name and then printing the pointer address using cout rather than the string at the new char*. You can do this by casting to void*, e.g.

```
cout << "Next address2 is " << (void*)(name + 1)
```

using C-style casts.